# match number with specific pattern in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a text like this:

text  = "56 ipv4 packets transmitted and 20 ipv6 packets transmitted"

from this pattern I want to extract 56 and 20 using **regexp in tcl**.

But my implementation extracts 4 (from ipv4) and 6 (from ipv6) as well.

```
[regexp -inline -all {\d+} $text]
```

Can someone help here ?

Comment: Use `[regexp -inline -all {\y\d+\y} $text]` or `[regexp -inline -all {\m\d+\M} $text]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use either `\y\d+\y` or `\m\d+\M` to match numbers as whole words, when they are not glued to neither letter, digit or underscore:

```
set text {56 ipv4 packets transmitted and 20 ipv6 packets transmitted}
set results [regexp -inline -all {\y\d+\y} $text]
puts $results
# => 56 20
set results2 [regexp -inline -all {\m\d+\M} $text]
puts $results2
# => 56 20
```

See the [Tcl demo](https://ideone.com/MgXOIS).

See [Tcl docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M54):

> `\m`
>          matches only at the beginning of a word
>   `\M`
>          matches only at the end of a word
>   `\y`
>          matches only at the beginning or end of a word

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
set text {56 ipv4 packets transmitted and 20 ipv6 packets transmitted}
set nums [lmap word [split $text] {
   if {[string is integer -strict $word]} then {set word} else continue
}]
```

```
56 20
```